# Citus distributed table in all worker nodes

Tags: postgresql, citus

I'm trying out citus (docker-compose based on tutorial, 2 worker nodes). If I create a table and don't execute create_distributed_table the table is only created in the coordinator which seems to be according to the documentation, however, once I run create_distributed_table and connect to coordinator and worker nodes, the table is present in all (with all rows) and with the actual table name (no table_name_shardid).

If I run the following query though:

```
SELECT
    shardid,
    node.nodename,
    node.nodeport
FROM pg_dist_placement placement
JOIN pg_dist_node node
  ON placement.groupid = node.groupid
 AND node.noderole = 'primary'::noderole
WHERE shardid = 102056;
```

I get the shard should only be present in one of the nodes:

102056  "worker1b"  5432

Running `select * from citus_get_active_worker_nodes()` on coordinator I get:

"worker2a"  5432

"worker1b"  5432

Answer (score 0):

Citus masks shard tables. To be able to query them, this is required:

Run `select * from citus_shards` to identify the shard table name

Then:
https://docs.citusdata.com/en/latest/develop/api_guc.html#citus-show-shards-for-app-name-prefixes-text

Then we can query the shard table.